# Format number with . as thousand separator and no decimals

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I've alreayd checked here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-visualization-api/4qCeUgE-OmU
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#Format
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#numberformatter

I want to display the number on the x-axis in a graph drawn with Google Charts with no decimals and a `.` as the thousand separator.

```
var options = {
    hAxis: {
        title: 'Month'
    },
    vAxis: {
        title: 'Price (€)', format: '#.###'
    }
};
```

So 3200 should be shown as 3.200

I've already tried for the `format` variable:

```
#.#
#.###
#
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since the `format` option will not work in this situation,
you can provide your own `ticks` for `vAxis`...

use object notation for each tick

```
{
   v: value,
   f: formattedValue
}
```

use google's [NumberFormat class](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#numberformat)...

```
var formatNumber = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
  fractionDigits: 0,
  groupingSymbol: '.'
});
```

format each tick using the `formatValue` method

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('number', 'x');
    data.addColumn('number', 'y');
    data.addRows([
      [1, 3000],
      [2, 3100],
      [3, 3200],
      [4, 3300],
      [5, 3400],
    ]);

    var formatNumber = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
      fractionDigits: 0,
      groupingSymbol: '.'
    });

    var columnRange = data.getColumnRange(1);
    var ticks = [];
    for (var i = columnRange.min; i <= columnRange.max; i=i+100) {
      ticks.push({
        v: i,
        f: formatNumber.formatValue(i)
      });
    }

    var options = {
      hAxis: {
        title: 'Month'
      },
      vAxis: {
        ticks: ticks,
        title: 'Price (€)'
      }
    };

    var container = document.getElementById('chart');
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(container);
    chart.draw(data, options);
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```